# Issue with unexpected characters/symbols showing in GUIs

Tags: linux, arch-linux, xorg, fonts, gui

I've recently run into a problem on my system where 'weird' characters will show up in text in certain(?) desktop applications. *(examples below)*

E.g. if I type *'fi'* in my browser's URL field, it will show up as a telephone symbol once I enter the *'i'* character. And *'fl'* will turn into what appears to be the Commodore "chickenlips" logo when entering the *'l'*.

There's no actual change/corruption of the character(s) going on. That is to say the problem seems to only be the displaying/rendering of them. *'fi'* and *'fl'* will still actually be *'fi'* and *'fl'* when i copy-paste the text etc.

I've tried to set the desired font(s) using e.g `gnome-tweaks`, `lxappearance` and *`gtk2_prefs`* . Nothing seems out of the ordinary there, though the problem still persists.

In the screenshots below, "Noto Sans" *(light 12)* font is being used, but I've also tried e.g Ubuntu's font.

I use fluxbox window manager, but I've also tried switching a few styles for it, with no apparent luck.

At the moment, I'm a bit confused as to where to even look for what might be the cause of this.

A few examples:

Eclipse IDE 'Create new file' dialog
[image: From Eclipse's Create New File dialog]

Brave browser URL field
[image: From Brave browser's URL field]

While I've yet to figure out a sensible solution, @blaimi's comment mentioning **https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/issues/254** definitely seem to be descriptive of the very exact problem I'm having.

Comment: Working as intended. You simply have to speciphone a folder. No need to ask on Stackovercow

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a problem with resolving [ligatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_ligature).

This can happen if your fontconfig-cache is corrupted. You can clear it by deleting/renaming `~/.cache/fontconfig` and reboot.

copy&pasting in editors works, because they usually don't use ligatures in mono-fonts.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a go

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not seem to make any difference. (i renamed __~/.cache/fontconfig__ to __~/.cache/old_fontconfig__ , then a __sudo reboot__)

Comment: hmm … can you also try renaming /var/cache/fontconfig?

Comment: did you make any updates recently?

Comment: Removing __/var/cache/fontconfig__ made no difference. 

And yeah, i suspect the problem came about after an update. Though, unfortunately i have no way of knowing specifically when the problem began, since i believe it took a short while before i even noticed it. And, i've probably ran updates at least once or twice after that.

Comment: Speaking of updates. I notice there now appears to be quite a slew of Arch updates out. So, i'll try to see if some of those might might resolve it. I've prepared a list of the updates (and their versions), just in case something there solves it, and will post that if it does.

**(though, i've no idea how to identify any actual culprit, or version, if it does resolve itself)**

Comment: maybe a look at this helps: https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/issues/254 didn't read it, but the ligature-replacements have the same symbols

Comment: Awesome :D I do actually have the 'Nerd'/Patched fonts on my system. So that definitely seems to be someone describing having my exact problem. Thanks again!

Comment: Based on the github link, i eventually decided to try a `yay -R nerd-fonts-git` (after having first tried installing e.g `nerd-fonts-complete` etc.); And removing that package immediately solved the problem on my end.

Answer (score 0):

*(based off of clue in comment by blaimi (https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/issues/254))*

**NOTE:** The below can hardly be called a solution per se, or barely even considered a workaround..And it's perhaps only *Arch*- and/or *Manjaro*- related.. But i'll leave this here in case it might be of use to others whom might hopefully be able to come up with a better answer than a mere uninstallation of package(s).

For me, deciding to remove the `nerd-fonts(-git)` package immediately resolved the issue.

- *(simply attempting uninstalling and replacing it with `nerd-fonts-complete` and/or their `*-git` alternatives, did not solve it for me)*

> $ yay -R nerd-fonts-git

- Keep in mind that in case you've set specific apps such as e.g *Terminator*, to use any *non- default/system-theme* fonts, you'll probably want to doublecheck their configurations just in case you had them set to using a then non-existing font.

Afterwards, i ran `fc-cache --force` again *(though this might not even be necessary..)*. I then pkill'ed Brave browser, loaded it up again, and the telephones were gone :)

Though, I wish i knew *why*, *how*, and of a most likely much better 'solution' than removing it..Unfortunately, fonts are a mystery to me.

**PS:** It's perhaps worth noting that [at the time of this writing](https://web.archive.org/web/20201019184355/https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/nerd-fonts-git/#comment-755273) the *[nerd-fonts-git](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/nerd-fonts-git/)* AUR package was currently marked as being *'out of date / orphan' (version r549.c89aeaa7-1)*